# Automate Spreadsheet Transformations

Tags: iphone, macos, spreadsheet

Every month I process a vendor's MS Excel spreadsheet for my work.  I have to remove columns, rename columns, re-format columns, and then email the resulting spreadsheet to colleagues.

Is there a way, in Excel or Numbers or programmatically, to automate this extremely repetitive process?

Thanks,
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Excel for Mac supports Applescript so you could script the process. [RealBasic](http://www.realsoftware.com/realbasic/) can automate Excel. Excel for Mac used (5+ years ago) to ship with a reduced version of it. Don't know if it still does.

Applescript support in iWork Numbers is rather good so if you have Numbers I would suggest importing into Numbers and running the script there.